# How can i apply my tax rate array to my junit test cases?

Tags: java

This code checks salaries and applying the tax-rate, I have some new logic that I have to apply but I have to maintain values because they have to pass my JUnit test. i currently passing a few test cases now.

Logic I want to apply

```
from:
float rate = 0, r1 = 0 ,r2 = 0;
int i = 0;
to 
System.out.println("Total Paid: " + totalPaid);
```

to rest of my code, but just need a little direction or hint

```
package edu.citytech.taxes.service;

import gov.irs.marignal.taxrate.ICalculate;
import gov.irs.marignal.taxrate.Status;
import static gov.irs.marignal.taxrate.Status.SINGLE;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static gov.irs.marignal.taxrate.Status.MARRIED;
import static gov.irs.marignal.taxrate.Status.HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD;

public class MarginalTax implements ICalculate {

  float rate = 0, r1 = 0 ,r2 = 0;

    // change 9_700 to 9_000 to match test case
    TaxRate[] taxRateForAll = {
              new TaxRate(rate = .10f, r1 = 9_000, r2 = 0, SINGLE)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .12f, r1 = 39475, r2 = 9_000, SINGLE)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .22f, r1 = 84200, r2 = 39475, SINGLE)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .24f, r1 = 160725, r2 = 84200, SINGLE)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .32f, r1 = 204100, r2 = 160725, SINGLE)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .35f, r1 = 510300, r2 = 204100, SINGLE)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .37f, r1 = 999999999, r2 = 510300, SINGLE)

              ,new TaxRate(rate = .10f, r1 = 19400, r2 = 0, MARRIED)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .12f, r1 = 78950, r2 = 19400, MARRIED)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .22f, r1 = 168400, r2 = 78950, MARRIED)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .24f, r1 = 321450, r2 = 168400, MARRIED)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .32f, r1 = 408200, r2 = 321450, MARRIED)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .35f, r1 = 612350, r2 = 408200, MARRIED)
              ,new TaxRate(rate = .37f, r1 = 999999999, r2 = 612350, MARRIED)

      ,new TaxRate(rate = .10f, r1 = 13850, r2 = 0, HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD)
      ,new TaxRate(rate = .12f, r1 = 52850, r2 = 13850, HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD)
      ,new TaxRate(rate = .22f, r1 = 84200, r2 = 52850, HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD)
      ,new TaxRate(rate = .24f, r1 = 160000, r2 = 84200, HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD)
      ,new TaxRate(rate = .32f, r1 = 204100, r2 = 160000, HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD)
      ,new TaxRate(rate = .35f, r1 = 510300, r2 = 204100, HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD)
   ,new TaxRate(rate = .37f, r1 = 999999999, r2 = 510300, HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD)

    };



 @Override
  public float getTaxRate(Status status, int year, float salary) {
    float taxPaid = 0f;


    int i = 0;



     TaxRate [] taxRate = Arrays.stream(taxRateForAll)
              .filter(m -> m.status == status.SINGLE)
              .toArray(TaxRate[]::new);


      while(salary > taxRate[i].r1){

                  taxPaid = (taxRate[i].r1 - taxRate[i].r2) * taxRate[i].rate;
                  taxRate[i].taxPaid = taxPaid;
                  System.out.println(taxRate[i]);
                i++;

          }

         taxPaid = (salary - taxRate[i].r2) * taxRate[i].rate;

          taxRate[i].taxPaid = taxPaid;


        double totalPaid = Arrays.stream(taxRate)
                              .filter(f -> f.taxPaid != 0)
                              .mapToDouble(m -> m.taxPaid)
                              .sum();






    //Original Logic//////////////////////////////////////////

    if (status == Status.SINGLE && year == 2019 && salary <= 9_700) {
    taxPaid = salary * .10f;

    }

    // 12% Bracket: ($39,475 - $9,700) x 12% = $3573

    if (status == Status.SINGLE && year == 2019 && salary > 9700 && salary <= 39_475) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 9_700;
        taxPaid = 970f + (salaryDifference * .12f);

    }

    // 22% Bracket: ($84,200 - $39,475) x 22% = $9,839.00

    if (status == Status.SINGLE && year == 2019 && salary > 39_475 && salary <= 84_200) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 39_475;
        taxPaid = 3_573.00f + 970f + (salaryDifference * .22f);

    }

    // 24% Bracket: ($160,725 - $84,200) x 24& = $18,366.00

    if (status == Status.SINGLE && year == 2019 && salary > 84_200 && salary <= 160_725) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 84_200;
        taxPaid = 9_839.50f + 3_573.00f + 970f + (salaryDifference * .24f);

    }

    // 32% Bracket: ($204,100 - $160,725) x 32& = $13,880.00

    if (status == Status.SINGLE && year == 2019 && salary > 160_725 && salary <= 204_100) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 160_725;
        taxPaid = 18_366.00f + 9_839.50f + 3_573.00f + 970f + (salaryDifference * .32f);

    }

    // 35% Bracket: ($510,300 - $204,100) x 35& = $107170

    if (status == Status.SINGLE && year == 2019 && salary > 204_100 && salary <= 510_300) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 204_100;
        taxPaid = 13_880.00f + 18_366.00f + 9_839.50f + 3_573.00f + 970f + (salaryDifference * .35f);

    }

    // 37% Bracket: ($) x 37& = ??

    if (status == Status.SINGLE && year == 2019 && salary > 510_300) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 510_300;
        taxPaid = 107_170.00f + 13_880.00f + 18_366.00f + 9_839.50f + 3_573.00f + 970f + (salaryDifference * .37f);

    }

    // 10% = 19400 - 0 * 10% = 1940

    if (status == Status.MARRIED && year == 2019 && salary <= 19_400) {

        taxPaid = salary * .10f;

    }

    // 12% Bracket: ($78,950 - $19,400) x 12% = $7,146

    if (status == Status.MARRIED && year == 2019 && salary > 19_400 && salary <= 78_950) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 19_400;
        taxPaid = 1_940.00f + (salaryDifference * .12f);

    }

    // 22% Bracket: ($168,400 - $78,950) x 22% = $19,679.00

    if (status == Status.MARRIED && year == 2019 && salary > 78_950 && salary <= 168_400) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 78_950;
        taxPaid = 7_146.00f + 1_940.00f + (salaryDifference * .22f);

    }

    // 24% Bracket: ($321,450 - $168,400) x 24% = $36,732 + 28735

    if (status == Status.MARRIED && year == 2019 && salary > 168_400 && salary <= 321_450) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 168_400;
        taxPaid = 19_679.00f + 7_146.00f + 1_940.00f + (salaryDifference * .24f);

    }

    // 32% Bracket: ($408,200 - $321,450) x 32% = $27760

    if (status == Status.MARRIED && year == 2019 && salary > 321_450 && salary <= 408_200) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 321_450;
        taxPaid = 36_732.00f + 19_679.00f + 7_146.00f + 1_940.00f + (salaryDifference * .32f);

    }

    // 35% Bracket: ($612_350 - $408,200) x 35% = $71_452.5

    if (status == Status.MARRIED && year == 2019 && salary > 408_200 && salary <= 612_350) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 408_200;
        taxPaid = 27_760.00f + 36_732.00f + 19_679.00f + 7_146.00f + 1_940.00f + (salaryDifference * .35f);

    }

    // 37% Bracket: (??? - $612_350) x 37% = ??? 164_709.5

    if (status == Status.MARRIED && year == 2019 && salary > 612_350) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 612_350;
        taxPaid = 71_452.50f + 27_760.00f + 36_732.00f + 19_679.00f + 7_146.00f + 1_940.00f
                + (salaryDifference * .37f);

    }

    // 10% = 13_850 - 0 * 10% = 1385

    if (status == Status.HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD && year == 2019 && salary <= 13_850) {

        taxPaid = salary * .10f;

    }

    // 12% = 52_850 - 13_850 * 12% = 4680

    if (status == Status.HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD && year == 2019 && salary > 13_850 && salary <= 52_850) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 13_850;
        taxPaid = 1_385.00f + (salaryDifference * .12f);

    }

    // 22% = 84_200 - 52_850 * 22% = 6897

    if (status == Status.HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD && year == 2019 && salary > 52_850 && salary <= 84_200) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 52_850;
        taxPaid = 4_680.00f + 1_385.00f + (salaryDifference * .22f);

    }

    // 24% = 160_000 - 84_200 * 24% = 18192

    if (status == Status.HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD && year == 2019 && salary > 84_200 && salary <= 160_000) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 84_200;
        taxPaid = 6_897.00f + 4_680.00f + 1_385.00f + (salaryDifference * .24f);

    }

    // 32% = 204_100 - 160_000 * 32% = 14112

    if (status == Status.HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD && year == 2019 && salary > 160_000 && salary <= 204_100) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 160_000;
        taxPaid = 18_192.00f + 6_897.00f + 4_680.00f + 1_385.00f + (salaryDifference * .32f);

    }

    // 35% = 510_300 - 204_100 * 35% = 107170

    if (status == Status.HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD && year == 2019 && salary > 204_100 && salary <= 510_300) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 204_100;
        taxPaid = 14_112.00f + 18_192.00f + 6_897.00f + 4_680.00f + 1_385.00f + (salaryDifference * .35f);

    }

    // 37% = ??? - 510_300 * 37% = ??? 152_436 +

    if (status == Status.HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD && year == 2019 && salary > 510_300) {

        float salaryDifference = salary - 510_300;
        taxPaid = 107_170.00f + 14_112.00f + 18_192.00f + 6_897.00f + 4_680.00f + 1_385.00f
                + (salaryDifference * .37f);

      }

     //return taxPaid;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    return (float)totalPaid;

      }
   }
```

this is my tax rate class

```
package edu.citytech.taxes.service;

import gov.irs.marignal.taxrate.Status;

public class TaxRate {

public final float rate;
public final float r1;
public final float r2;
public final Status status;
public float taxPaid;

/**
 * 
 * @param rate
 * @param r1
 * @param r2
 * @param status
 */
public TaxRate(float rate, float r1, float r2, Status status) {
    super();
    this.rate = rate;
    this.r1 = r1;
    this.r2 = r2;
    this.status = status;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TaxRate [rate=" + rate + ", r1=" + r1 + ", r2=" + r2 + ", status=" + status + ", taxPaid=" + taxPaid
            + "]";
}


}
```

These are the classes being implemented

```
package gov.irs.marignal.taxrate;

public interface ICalculate {

float getTaxRate(Status status, int year, float salary);

}

package gov.irs.marignal.taxrate;

public enum Status {    
MARRIED, SINGLE, HEAD_OF_HOUSE_HOLD
}
```

And this is the juint for the single people i just wanna figure that one out and try to do the others my self

```
package edu.citytech.taxes.test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import edu.citytech.taxes.service.MarginalTax;
import gov.irs.marignal.taxrate.ICalculate;
import gov.irs.marignal.taxrate.Status;

class TestSingle {

@Test
@DisplayName("test for single people 900k") // generates name for test name is junit report
void test() {

    ICalculate tax = new MarginalTax();
    float taxPaid = tax.getTaxRate(Status.SINGLE, 2019, 9_000);
    boolean status = taxPaid == 900;
    assertTrue(status, "900 was expected wrong values" + taxPaid);// assert produce junit report
}

@Test
@DisplayName("test for single people 1000k") // generates name for test name is junit report
void test2() {

    ICalculate tax = new MarginalTax();
    float taxPaid = tax.getTaxRate(Status.SINGLE, 2019, 10_000);
    boolean status = taxPaid == 1006;
    assertTrue(status, "1006 was expected wrong values" + taxPaid);// assert produce junit report
}

@Test
@DisplayName("test for single people 10") // generates name for test name is junit report
void test3() {

    ICalculate tax = new MarginalTax();
    float taxPaid = tax.getTaxRate(Status.SINGLE, 2019, 10);
    boolean status = taxPaid == 1;
    assertTrue(status, "1 was expected wrong values" + taxPaid);// assert produce junit report
}

@Test
@DisplayName("test for single people 150,000") // generates name for test name is junit report
void test4() {

    ICalculate tax = new MarginalTax();
    float taxPaid = tax.getTaxRate(Status.SINGLE, 2019, 150_000);
    boolean status = taxPaid == 30_174.50;
    assertTrue(status, "30_174.50 was expected wrong values" + taxPaid);// assert produce junit report
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Test for single people 200,000")
void test5() {

    ICalculate tax = new MarginalTax();
    float taxPaid = tax.getTaxRate(Status.SINGLE, 2019, 200_000);
    boolean status = taxPaid == 45_316.50;

    assertTrue(status, "45_316.50 was expected wrong value" + taxPaid);
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Test for single people 300,000")
void test6() {

    ICalculate tax = new MarginalTax();
    float taxPaid = tax.getTaxRate(Status.SINGLE, 2019, 300_000);
    boolean status = taxPaid == 80_193.50;

    assertTrue(status, "80_193.50 was expected wrong value" + taxPaid);
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Test for single people 600,000")
void test7() {

    ICalculate tax = new MarginalTax();
    float taxPaid = tax.getTaxRate(Status.SINGLE, 2019, 600_000);
    boolean status = taxPaid == 186_987.50;

    assertTrue(status, "186_987.50 was expected wrong value" + taxPaid);
   }


 }
```

Comment: Can you pass taxRateForAll in to MarginalTax's constructor? Or allow taxRateForAll  to be set from a unit test? Then you can create a class with real rates for actual usage, and a test rates for unit tests.

Comment: Yeah, I cant pass the taxRateForAll into the MarginalTax Constructor because im using a package imported from a jar that contains those two classes being implemented and im not sure about creating another JUnit test for taxes im still new to JUnit testing and the goal is to have the junit test I have to pass first.